# What is Different Between How Azure File Sync Copies Files and How Regular Copy/Paste Works?

Tags: azure, azure-files

We set up Azure File Sync across 3 VMs in Azure running IIS 10 on Windows Server Datacenter 2016 in order to make a common group of files available to the application spread across these servers.

The weird thing is, when we paste files into one of the servers to initiate a sync, the web applications on the servers which received the files as part of the sync process crash, but the server in which we hand-pasted the files continues to function normally.

What is the difference between copying and pasting files by hand via RDP versus syncing the files via Azure File Sync?

I have tried pasting files by hand into each of the servers and have had 0 application crashes, but every server has crashed every time it receives files by the sync process.

The application crash itself is a 502.3 displayed in IIS coming from the application itself which is running dotnet core 2.1.